# Prove a group is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb N.$ How do I prove that $G$ is an abelian group with respect to the binary operation " * " defined by $\;a*b = a+b+11$ ?

Comment: There are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: We need for $G$ to be $\mathbb N$, or the binary operation you posted is not truly a binary operation on a subset of $\mathbb N$, at least insofar as $G$ will not be closed under the operation

Comment: Probably won't be a group. How do you want to invert in $\mathbb{N}$? ($\mathbb{N}$ is not even a group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, we need for $G$ to be $\mathbb N$, and not a subset of $\mathbb N$, unless we know specifically what the subset consists of: all non-negative multiples of $11$? All odd elements in $\mathbb N$? Otherwise, the "binary operation" you posted is not truly be a binary operation on any arbitrary subset of $\mathbb N$, at least insofar as $G$ risks not be closed under the operation.

Even if we take $G = \mathbb N$,
there are  problems.

It is true that the operation is ***associative*** and commutative. (To be an abelian group, we need to ensure the operation is commutative on $G$.)

But the ***identity*** of $G$ would necessarily have to be $-11$, but $-11 \notin \mathbb N$, and in any case, $G$ would not be closed under taking ***inverses***.

The bottom line is that $G$ fails to be a group, since not all the group axioms hold.

Comment: Nice write-up +1